# Negative binomial distribution vs binomial distribution?

Tags: probability

> A Basketball player sink a ball in probability of 60%, independently.
>   What is the probability he will success in 5 out 6 shots?

Every event is independent and has $p=0.6$, and $q=0.4$, and we want 5 out of 6 (no matter the order). 

is it $Bin\sim (6,0.6)$ therefore it is ${6\choose 5}*0.6^5*0.4=0.186$

or is it $BN\sim (5,0.6)$? in general when should I use Negative binomial distribution rather than binomial distribution?

Comment: You can compute it without referring to any "distribution"... (Binomial - number of successes in $n$ trials)

Comment: yes it is $\frac{{6\choose 5}{2\choose 1}}{2^6}$, I am trying to understand when to use negative binomial distribution vs binomial distribution

Comment: NB - number of successes before $n$ failures occur.

Comment: @d.k.o. so is this case I have no way to use NB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative binomial is not useful here. That's the distribution for the number of successes before the $n$-th failure.

Here you should use the binomial distribution,